# Django model validation in clean or in separate validators?

Tags: django, validation, django-rest-framework, model, django-validation

I am pretty new to Django and I was wondering what is the best method to validate your models in Django? Are there any advantages to using clean vs adding validators to your models? By validators I mean when you do declare the field, populating the validator=[] list. I find the models to be easier to read with the validators in another package, and declared in the field list. Also, I try to validate the data before in services, before initializing the models. What do you think / prefer? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that a validator will apply to model objects created in forms and directly, i.e.:

```py
form = MyModelForm(...
# and
my_model = MyModel(...
```

Whereas clean will only apply to a form. If you are creating model objects outside of forms then you should consider using validators. You might also find using validators to be a cleaner, more DRY method of checking what is created rather than overriding form clean functions.